# iText - PdfPTable doesn't show Cyrillic(Russian) symbols

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm sorry for my English.
I'm trying to create table with PdfPTable(iText library).
Table show me empty column![enter image description here][1]

```
public class CreatePDF {
File file;
BaseFont bf;
Font f_title;
Font f_text;

public void setFont() throws DocumentException, IOException{
    try{
        bf = BaseFont.createFont("/fonts/Times_New_Roman.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H , BaseFont.EMBEDDED); 
        f_title = new Font(bf, 14 );
        f_text = new Font(bf);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void make_invoice() throws DocumentException, IOException{
    setFont();
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
    try{
        file = new File("invoice.pdf");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(file));
        doc.open();
        Paragraph title = new Paragraph();
        title.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        title.setFont(f_title);
        title.add("Счет фактура");//this work!

        doc.add(create_table());

        doc.close();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public PdfPTable create_table() throws DocumentException{
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table.setSpacingBefore(5f);

    PdfPCell cell;

    Phrase ph = new Phrase("Номер");//it's doesn't work ((
    ph.setFont(f_text);

    cell = new PdfPCell(ph);
    table.addCell(cell);
    table.addCell("Nuber");

    return table;
}
```

I tried use other fonts but it doesn't help me(((

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: try `new Phrase("Номер", font)`

Comment: Thanks!! Why ph.setFont(f_text); is not work?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `setFont()`, you change the font of the `Phrase` for all the content that is added *after* the font was set. The content `"Номер"` was already present in the `Phrase` *before* you changed it. Hence `"Номер"` was represented in the default font Helvetica. As Helvetica doesn't know how to represent Cyrillic glyphs, the text wasn't rendered.

Comment: if you indicate the proper way to do with an example it would help understand you... still dont understand your answer