# Why can't I set the font of a Phrase (or Paragraph)?

Tags: c#, fonts, itext, phrase

I'm starting with itextsharp and wondering if there is any reason why if I set the font of a phrase after the construction it doesn't work.
Is there any reason, do I miss something?

```
 iTextSharp.text.Font f = PdfFontFactory.GetComic();
 f.SetStyle(PdfFontStyle.BOLD);
 Color c = Color.DarkRed;
 f.SetColor(c.R,c.G,c.B);
 f.Size = 20;
 Document document = new Document();
 try
 {
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new System.IO.FileStream("PhraseTest.pdf",   FileMode.Create));
    document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
    document.Open();
    Phrase titreFormules = new Phrase("Nos formules",f); //THIS WORKS
    // titreFormules.Font = f; // THIS DOESN'T WORK!
    document.Add(titreFormules);
    document.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented in my book.

- A `Chunk` is an atomic part of text in the sense that all the text in a `Chunk` has the same font family, font size, font color,...
- A `Phrase` is a collection of `Chunk` objects and as such a `Phrase` can contain different 'atoms' of text using different fonts.

In your example `"Nos formules"` will be written in Helvetica. You change the font *after* the Helvetica `Chunk` with the text `"Nos formules"` was added to the `Phrase`.As you didn't add anything else to `titreFormules`, the font "Comic" is never used.

This is also what I meant when I answered the question [iText - PdfPTable doesn't show Cyrillic(Russian) symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533331/itext-pdfptable-doesnt-show-cyrillicrussian-symbols):

> When you use `setFont()`, you change the font of the `Phrase` for all the content that is added *after* the font was set.

Comment: That such questions come so often, perhaps indicates that people want a functionality to change the fonts already used in a phrase instead of thinking of proper font-use beforehand. (And admittedly, a property or attribute of a `Phrase` class called `Font` *feels* like operating on the existing content, too.)

Comment: I understand better how it's working. But as mkl said the property push me to understand as there are constructor for Phrase and Paragraph without font parameter (even default font) I was thinking ok let get a phrase or paragraph with such text and set now it's property. Anyway it's working like that so no problem for me. Thanks for your clear answer